# Allow tags in React Quill component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill

I am trying to load following content into a ReactQuill component but it keeps stripping away its inner html tags such as `<mark>`.

```
<mark><i><b>[CLIENT NAME]</b></i></mark>
```

The component turns it into following:

```
<p><strong><em>[CLIENT NAME]</em></strong></p>
```

Quill Componenet:

```
<ReactQuill
 {...{
   key: 'content',
   value: this.state.content,
   onChange: handleContent,
 }}
/>
```

Is there a way to add exceptions for tags so that the component will ignore a tag?

Comment: How do you load your contents, directly in your quill DOM node before instanciating it?

Comment: Content updates via state.

Comment: Sorry, dunno how ReactQuill works with content, I use Quill directly in my React app. You might want to create a new format, MarkFormat and register it to Quill (with Parchment). That way, when Quill will see your html, it would handle and support your mark tag because it has the format registered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to define your custom format, [see this](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill#custom-formats). Defining a `Mark` format should allow Quill to recognise and properly handle your html

```
class MarkBlot extends Inline { }
MarkBlot.blotName = 'mark';
MarkBlot.tagName = 'mark';
Quill.register(MarkBlot);
```